# Java spring annotation attribute

Tags: java, spring, validation, jakarta-ee

I have a post method receiving an object as parameter, in this object I have an attribute with annotations @ValidDate and @NotEmpty.
in another method I want to use the same object but I just want annotation @ValidDate on the attribute.
It's possible ?

the attribute :

```
@NotEmpty 
@ValidDate 
private String installDate;
```

the function :

```
public String findLinksByCriteria(@Valid @ModelAttribute LinkForm link, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return ViewConstants.LINK_SEARCH_VIEW;
    }
```

Comment: So in situation 1 you want `installDate` to be `@NotEmpty` while in situation 2 it may be empty? I this isn't possible with annotations. I suggest you remove the `@NotEmpty` annotation and check if `installDate` is empty or not by hand when the situation asks for it.

Comment: @Tom yes it's exactly that I want. Ok I will check it by hand. thank you for reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably one of these thing with multiple solutions. You can remove the optional constraint and do it manually however if you want to keep it strictly within the context of the Bean Validation API then you can do it using validation groups.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gkahp/index.html

> Constraints may be added to one or more groups. Constraint groups are
>   used to create subsets of constraints, so only certain constraints
>   will be validated for a particular object. By default, all constraints
>   are included in the Default constraint group.

By using Spring's `@Validated` annotation rather than `@Valid` you can specify one or more groups of constraints to be applied for any given case.

There is a detailed example here:

http://blog.codeleak.pl/2014/08/validation-groups-in-spring-mvc.html